# No Post Data - Testing Django View with AJAX Request

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm currently testing my Django application in order to add some CI/CD to it. However, most of my views contain an AJAX section for requests sent by the frontend. I saw that for testing those I can only just do something like this:

```
response: HttpResponseBase = self.client.post(
        path=self.my_page_url,
        content_type='application/json',
        HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest',
        data={
            'id': '123456',
            'operation': "Fill Details"
        }
    )
```

The `XMLHttpRequest` is making most of the magic here (I think), by simulating the headers that an AJAX request would have. However, in my view I have a section where I do: `request.POST['operation']`, but this seems to fail during tests since apparently no data is passed through the `POST` attribute. Here's the code of the view that I'm using right now:

```
MyView(request):
   is_ajax: bool = request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
   if is_ajax:
      operation = request.POST['operation']
```

I checked and my data is being passed in `request.body`. I could include an or statement, but it would be ideal if the code for views was not modified because of tests. Is there any way to get the `client.post` method to pass the data through the POST attribute?

Comment: Your usage of TestClient.post seems fine. Could you provide the code of your view ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code for my view

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate ajax like POST using the python requests library.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36',
}


data = {
            'id': '123456',
            'operation': "Fill Details"
        }

session = requests.Session()
session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This was a step in the right direction. I changed the `application/json` argument to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I'm getting data inside of request.POST now. The thing is, its being received as a dictionary with a stringified version of the data (instead of an actual dictionary with the sent data). Will probably need to parse the string or make it so that an actual dictionary is passed.